# Gettng the indexes of items and putting the indexes in a different array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am specifically wondering why this solution does not work.

You are supposed to create a function that returns the indices of all occurrences of an item in the array.

Given the array ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']

I am wanting to find all the indexes of the element 'a', and put it in another array

I know there are different ways to do this, but i did this

```
function getIndices(arr, el) {
    a = [];
    for(i of arr){
        if(i === el) a.push(Number(arr.indexOf(i)));
    }
    return a;
}
```

but when i ran it all that returned was [0, 0, 0, 0]
Why is this?

Comment: `indexOf()` always returns the index of the first match.

Comment: I dont think you can use indexOf in this case, @Barmar is correct that the indexOf returns the first occurence of the array item. Maybe you should use `for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { ... }` instead so you have the indexes..

Comment: @reikyoushin They wrote that they know there are other ways.

Comment: Yeah that's why I'm pointing out that using indexOf might not get the desired solution here..

Comment: They already know that, that's why they posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this, use:

```
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
    if (arr[i] === el) {
        a.push(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @reikyoushin and @Barmer mention in the comments, `indexOf` returns the index of the first element.

A nicer solution would be to try this:

```js
function indexOfElement(value, index, array) {
  if(value === this.searchElement)
    return index;
}

const inputArray = [1, 4, 7, 22, 2, 7, 7, 3];
const indices    = inputArray
                   .map(indexOfElement, { searchElement: 7 })
                   .filter((e) => e !== undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
arr = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a']
el = 'a'
a = []

arr.forEach(function (value,i){
  if (value === el) a.push(i);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `indexOf` second parameter `fromIndex`.
Here is your code with this modification.

```js
function getIndices(arr, el) {
  a = [];
  let last = -1;
  for (i of arr) {
    if (i === el) a.push(Number(last = arr.indexOf(i, last+1)));
  }
  return a;
}

const data = ["a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"];
console.log(getIndices(data, "a"));
```

Alternatively using `reduce`

```js
const getIndices2 = (arr, el) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
    if (cur === el) acc.push(i);
    return acc;
  }, []);

const data = ["a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a"];
console.log(getIndices2(data, "a"));
```